# All CheckBox gets unchecked on save when all other checkboxes are checked

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have a jquery method that controls the checkbox events.

When I click on save, my "check all" checkbox gets unchecked. Weird thing is that when I put a breakpoint while debugging, my "check all" checkbox gets checked and remains checked.

Code of the method called on page load:

```
function checkIfAllCheckboxesSelected(){
    var a = $("input[type='checkbox'].groupNames");
    if(a.length !=0)
    {
        if(a.length == (a.filter(":checked").length)){
           $('.allRecordsGroups').prop("checked",true);
        }
        else{
            $('.allRecordsGroups').prop("checked",false);
        }
    }   
}
```

Is something wrong with my method? I debugged everything, there is no other event that gets fired.

Here's my save method. I call this method on save in my jsp.

```
<script>
   function saveForm(){
     $("#submitForm1").val("NO");
     $("#sfForm").submit();
   }  
</script>
```

My full jsp page is:

```
<div class="errMsg"><img src="http://www.equifax.com/fusion/images/cms/error-small.png" /></div>


  <h2 class="fusion-h3Title">New Sample File Setup <span class="fusion-Description">Complete the Required Information, and click 'Save' or 'Submit'.</span></h2>


      <span class="line"></span>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <sf:form  action="/audit/savesfsetup?projectNumber=${project.projectNumber}" modelAttribute="sfForm" method="post">
      <div class="refineParam">
        <input type="hidden" name="projectNumber" value="${project.projectNumber}"/>
        <sf:input type="hidden" path="id" value="${sfForm.id}"/>
        <sf:input type="hidden" path="assignedId" value="${sfForm.assignedId}"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="svAcceptRecs"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="svRejectRecs"/>
        <label>Process name:${sfForm.assignedId}</label> <sf:input type="text" path="name" value="" cssClass="required" maxLength="30"/> <span class="italicsTxt">(Custom Name)</span> 
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="fileSummary">
        <!-- include for process/Job fulfillment data input fields -->
        <%@ include file="../../process-fulfillment-details-withGroups.jsp" %>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="row">                        
        <label>Select All&nbsp;: &nbsp; &nbsp;</label>
          <sf:checkbox path="allRecords" id="allRecords"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row"> 
        <label>Records per Accept Level&nbsp;:&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
              <sf:input type="text" path="noOfAcceptRecs" />
        </div>

        <div class="row"> 
        <label>Records per Reject Level&nbsp;:&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;</label>
              <sf:input type="text" path="noOfRejectRecs" />
        </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="audit-sample">  
        <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${sfForm.holdForMove == 'Y'}">   
        <sf:checkbox path="holdForMove" value="Y" checked="checked"/>Hold for additional data append via Move Statements   
        </c:when>  
        <c:otherwise>
        <sf:checkbox path="holdForMove" value="Y"/>Hold for additional data append via Move Statements
        </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
        </div><br/>
        <span>        
        <sf:input type="hidden" path="submitForm" name="submitForm1" id="submitForm1"/>
        </span>
      </div>
      <br/>      
       <span class="line"></span>


          <div class="buttons">
            <a href="<c:url value="/audit/home?projectNumber=${project.projectNumber}"/>" class="orange-btn">&laquo; Back </a>
            <input type="button" value="Save"  onClick="saveForm()" class='orange-btn'/> 
            <input type="button" value="Submit &raquo;"  onClick="changeForm()" class='orange-btn'/>
         </div>
      </sf:form>


<script src="<s:url value='/resources'/>/js/cms_data_sf.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
    activateSelectedNav('#cms_project');
    activateTab('#audit');
</script>
<script>
   function saveForm(){
     $("#submitForm1").val("NO");
     $("#sfForm").submit();
   }

   function changeForm(){
     $("#submitForm1").val("YES");
     $("#sfForm").submit();
   }

</script>
```

And the js file used is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.validator.addMethod("unixFileName", function(value, element){
        return /^[a-zA-Z0-9_./-]+$/.test(value);
    });

    $.validator.addMethod("checkIfProcessDataChecked", function(value, element){

        if($("#submitForm1").val() == 'NO') { 
            return true;
        } 
        else {
            var selectedItem = "";
            $("#fromProcessId option").each(function(){
                if($(this).attr('selected') == 'selected') {
                    selectedItem = $(this).val();
                }
            });

            if(selectedItem == '0')
            {
                return false;
            }
            else return true;
        }

    });

    $.validator.addMethod("checkIfjobIdChecked", function(value, element){

        if($("#submitForm1").val() == 'NO') { 
            return true;
        } 
        else {
            var selectedItem = "";
            $("#fromProcessId option").each(function(){
                if($(this).attr('selected') == 'selected') {
                    selectedItem = $(this).val();
                }
            });

            if(selectedItem == '0') {
                return true;
            }
            else {

                $("#jobId option").each(function(){
                    if($(this).attr('selected') == 'selected') {
                        selectedItem = $(this).val();
                    }
                });

                if(selectedItem == "") {
                    return false;
                }
                else return true;
            }
        }

    });

    $.validator.addMethod("checkIfItemIdChecked", function(value, element){

        if($("#submitForm1").val() == 'NO') { 
            return true;
        } 
        else {
            var selectedItem = "";
            $("#fromProcessId option").each(function(){
                if($(this).attr('selected') == 'selected') {
                    selectedItem = $(this).val();
                }
            });

            if(selectedItem == '0') {
                return true;
            }
            else {

                $("#jobId option").each(function(){
                    if($(this).attr('selected') == 'selected') {
                        selectedItem = $(this).val();
                    }
                });

                if(selectedItem == "") {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    $("#itemTableId option").each(function(){
                        if($(this).attr('selected') == 'selected') {
                            selectedItem = $(this).val();
                        }
                    });

                    if(selectedItem == "") {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else return true;

                }
            }
        }

    });

    $.validator.addMethod("checkAcceptRecs", function(value, element){

        if($("#submitForm1").val() == 'NO') {
            return true;
        } 
        else if($('input[type="checkbox"]'.allRecords).is(':checked')) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            var value = $("#noOfAcceptRecs").val();
            if(value != "" && !isNaN(value)) {
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
    });

    $.validator.addMethod("checkRejectRecs", function(value, element){

        if($("#submitForm1").val() == 'NO') {
            return true;
        } 
        else if($('input[type="checkbox"]'.allRecords).is(':checked'))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            var value = $("#noOfRejectRecs").val();
            if(value != "" && !isNaN(value))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
    });

    var container = $('div.errMsg');
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#sfForm').validate({
               errorContainer : container,
               errorLabelContainer: container,
               rules:{
                name:{unixFileName: true},
                fromProcessId:{checkIfProcessDataChecked: true},
                jobId:{checkIfjobIdChecked: true},
                itemTableId:{checkIfItemIdChecked: true},
                noOfAcceptRecs:{checkAcceptRecs: true},
                noOfRejectRecs:{checkRejectRecs: true}
               },
               messages:{
                    name:"Please enter alpha-numeric process name.<br>",
                    fromProcessId:"Please select the input process.<br>",
                    jobId:"Please select the input Job Id for process selected.<br>",
                    itemTableId:"Please select the input item for process selected.<br>",
                    noOfAcceptRecs:"Please enter valid Accept records <br>",
                    noOfRejectRecs:"Please enter valid Reject records <br>"
               }
            });
     });

    $('#allRecords').change(function(event) {

        if($(this).is(':checked')) {

            $('#svAcceptRecs').val($('#noOfAcceptRecs').val());
            $('#noOfAcceptRecs').val("");
            $("#noOfAcceptRecs").attr('readonly','readonly');

            $('#svRejectRecs').val($('#noOfRejectRecs').val());
            $('#noOfRejectRecs').val("");
            $("#noOfRejectRecs").attr('readonly','readonly');
        }
        else {

            $('#noOfAcceptRecs').val($('#svAcceptRecs').val());
            $("#noOfAcceptRecs").removeAttr('readonly','readonly');

            $('#noOfRejectRecs').val($('#svRejectRecs').val());
            $("#noOfRejectRecs").removeAttr('readonly','readonly');
        }
    });


});
```

Comment: Post your `save` method - is there a postback?

Comment: @tymeJV : I edited my post and posted the save method

Comment: Where do you call saveForm() ? What type is #submitForm1 ?. If not too long post your html form and the other listeners you have, the problem may be somewhere else

Comment: @RobinLeboeuf : I have posted the whole code.